# Reading string variables from different functions

Tags: python, tkinter

Im having trouble trying to get the values entered in to the Test number and the run time fields. the .get() function isn't returning anything. I don't know if I'm correctly storing the testnumber and runtime variables or if I need to change that to be able access the entered data later.

Any advice on how to fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x150")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Start')

def start():
    
    # test info window
    global win
    global testnumber_var
    global runtime_var

    
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.geometry("300x150")
    win.resizable(False, False)
    win.title('Test Information')
    
    # store test number and run time
    testnumber_var = tk.StringVar()
    runtime_var = tk.StringVar()

    # test info frame
    testinfo = ttk.Frame(win)
    testinfo.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)


    # test number
    testnumber_label = ttk.Label(testinfo, text="Test Number:")
    testnumber_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
    
    testnumber_entry = ttk.Entry(testinfo, textvariable=testnumber_var)
    testnumber_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
    testnumber_entry.focus()

    # runtime
    runtime_label = ttk.Label(testinfo, text="Run Time (Hours):")
    runtime_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    runtime_entry = ttk.Entry(testinfo, textvariable=runtime_var)
    runtime_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    # Next button
    next_button = ttk.Button(testinfo, text="Next", command=next_)
    next_button.pack(fill='x', expand=True, pady=10)


# entered test info
def next_():

    global test_number
    global run_time
    
    test_number = testnumber_var.get()
    run_time = runtime_var.get()
    
    print("TestNumber =", test_number) # don't get any values to return here
    print("RunTime =", run_time)
    
    win.destroy()

# start data input
ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Start',
    command=start).pack(expand=True)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is that all there is?  You aren't calling `start()` nor are you calling `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry didn't get the last little bit copied into here. I'm new to using python and haven't ever used tkinter before. Most of this is stuff I found looking up examples for what I wanted  to do. I'm trying to get this section:                                               
    global test_number
    global run_time
    
    test_number = testnumber_var.get()
    run_time = runtime_var.get()
    
    print("TestNumber =", test_number) # don't get any values to return here
    print("RunTime =", run_time)
    to work not sure if the variables won't return because of how the tk.StringVar()

Comment: It is because there are more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: As mentioned above you also have multiple instances of `Tk()` so in your `start()` function and any subsequent need for a window you should change to `Toplevel()`.

Comment: Thank you adding the top level and using the entry variable fixed it